# Verificação de url's - Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-2.0

Ao aprender a desenvolver aplicações utilizando Django é comum chegar a seguinte URL:

```
locahost:8000/minhaentidade/deletar/id
```

Porém um usuário mal intencionado pode alterar esse id e acabar deletando outra entidade. Sabendo disso, como posso verificar se os parâmetros da minha URL foram alterados? O django já possui alguma ferramenta para lidar com a situação? Ou existe alguma abordagem melhor para lidar com a situação?

Answer (score 0):

A abordagem mais correta para lidar com a situação é verificar se o usuário tem permissão para deletar o objeto antes de fazê-lo. Para isso, você precisa de um sistema de autenticação e de controle de acesso. O próprio Django fornece mecanismos prontos pra isso, mas também existem diversos outros apps de terceiros que implementam mecanismos mais complexos. As palavras chaves que você deve procurar, associada com Django, são: authentication backend, permissions, object permissions.

Sua preocupação com esse controle de acesso é um sinal que você está com as preocupações corretas. Mas, a ideia de controlar as URLs não é uma boa ideia. Lembre-se que o usuário sempre pode entrar manualmente com as URLs, sem ter recebido ela da sua aplicação.

Em programação WEB você precisa considerar que o usuário sempre tem controle total das requisições feitas a sua aplicação e que ele não é limitado pelo o que é exibido pra ele.